# @SessionScoped does not work. Jersey + Guice + GAE + Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, guice, session-scope

I have Jersey (1.17) + Guice (3.0) + GAE (1.9.24) Java application. And @SessionScoped annotation does not work.

I have

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionService implements Serializable {
  private String login = null;
  public void setLogin(String login) {this.login=login;}
  public String getLogin() {return this.login;}
}
```

In controller I have `SessionService` injected as `@Inject SessionService sessionService;`

Sessions are allowed in `appengine-web.xml` (`<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`)

On local Dev Server when I call `setLogin(XX)` and `getLogin` in 2 successive calls (2 accesses of page from the same browser window), I get `login=XX` as expected.

When deployed on GAE it creates new `SessionService` instance on every access from the same window in browser and thus returns `login=null`. So it doesn't keep login information in session and does not behave like expected from `@SessionScoped`.

Why does it not work? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: not sure how it works in Guice, but all session data should be Serializable (including SessionService I guess). because App Engine stores session in database

Comment: you're right Igor. in real code it is Serializable but i've forgotten to copy it into example here. it's corrected. it doesn't work on GAE with Serializable either.